# Firebreath how to know if my method is called without debugging

Tags: c++, objective-c, firebreath

I am using Objective-C++ in my firebreath project. The problem is that I am using Xcode 4 and I can not find the way to debug my project. So I have thought about if my method is been called from the web page.
Here is my source code:
In my `OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.h` class:

```
class OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI : public FB::JSAPIAuto
{
    public:
    OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI(const OpenOnDesktopPluginPtr& plugin, const FB::BrowserHostPtr& host);
    virtual ~OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI();
    OpenOnDesktopPluginPtr getPlugin();
   ...
   //This is my method 
   void runNotification();
   ...
};
```

In my `OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.mm` class:

```
OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI::OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI(const OpenOnDesktopPluginPtr& plugin,     const FB::BrowserHostPtr& host) : m_plugin(plugin), m_host(host)
{
    ...
    //Register my method
    registerMethod("runNotification",  make_method(this, &OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI::runNotification));
    ...
}
```

//DistributedNotification class is my objective-c class with the implementation for post a distributed notification.

```
void OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI::runNotification()
{
     DistributedNotification * notificationClass = [[DistributedNotification alloc] init]; 
    [notificationClass postNotification];
    [notificationClass release];
}
```

In my `FBControl.html`:
    ...
    function myFunction()
    {
         plugin().runNotification();
    }
    ...
    My new method 
    ...

I put my `DistributedNotification.mm` class in the

```
 Build Phases -> "Compile Sources"
```

for my plugin target.
But I don´t know if my `runNotification` method is called, because when (In my web page) I click on `My new method` link, nothing happens.

Comment: By putting good old traces in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repeat what I said on the forum when you ask; perhaps you haven't seen that answer yet:

First of all, you can debug with Xcode4, at least on some browsers; the trick is figuring out which process to connect to.

Secondly, you can always use NSLog to log things to the console. Thirdly, you could use log4cplus (see http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Logging).

Finally, you haven't specified what browser you're testing on, nor have you indicated what happens. It looks reasonable, but aparently doesn't work? What doesn't work? What does it do?

It's nearly impossible to give you any useful advice without detailed information about what you are encountering.

Comment: I am using firefox 3.6.23 and Chrome 14.0.835.202. When I click on the web page in "My new method" link, it calls a javascript function "myFunction". And this function calls the plugin method "runNotification". In this method I have objective-c code. Specifically I post a NSDistributedNotification. My problem is that the notification is never posted.

Comment: Now the javascript console is giving me an error message: "plugin().notification is not a function".

Comment: Sounds like your plugin isn't loading; are you sure you installed it correctly? does it show up in about:plugins? try getting FBTestPlugin to work first to make sure you understand how to load and run the plugin.

Comment: My plugin is working. If I look at "about:plugins" it shows me my plugin. I can see the "Plugin loaded!" alert message when the FBControl.html page is loaded. Also, the default functions are working properly. I can´t find the error :(

Comment: wait... plugin().notification is not a function? based on your code, plugin().runNotification should be a function. I don't see anywhere where "notification" is defined in your sample code. If the plugin loaded alert message occurs then there is likely a problem with the plugin() function in your javascript. I recmomend stopping into the IRC room for further help; this is already beyond the scope of this question. Alternately, open a new question that is relevant to the new problem you've learned about, since the logging/debugging question was answered.